# good memory class clean up practice?

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-leaks

I've recently been watching videos from google android devs about the importance of removing reference to objects when your done with them... I've implemented just a simple cleanup method. Will that actually work?

For example I do a lot of animation on views in my app. to make things cleaner I do my animations for a activity in different class. I pass a reference of the activity to the tweenanimation class.

```
public void onStart() {
    tweens = new TweenUm(this);
}
```

and in my onStop I do...

```
public void onStop() {
    tweens.cleanup();
    tweens = null;
    super.onStop();
}
```

my cleanup method looks something like...

```
public void cleanup() {
    mainAct = null;
    fab = null;
    fabcrad=null;
    searchFor = null;
}
```

`mainact` is the activity I passed in, plus other views i want to remove ref to.

Will this do any good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to add a method `cleanup`.

Because you are nulling the reference to the object `tweens`, if no other references are mantained in memory, `tweens` and all internal objects referenced only by tweens (mainAct, fab, fabcrad, searchFor) will be freed from memory by garbage collector.

Use a `cleanup` method only to close resources (like files, sockets and so on).

Note: while nulling tweens is important creating (and calling) cleanup is not a good choice, infact there are two possibilities:

- no other references to tweens exists, so nulling internal references is not necessary
- other references to tweens exists, in this case you probably will break internal state of tweens coming to a not valid state.

So generally if you don't need to close external opened resources it is not a good practice to use a cleanup method.

Comment: Ah great thanks, but in this circumstance, its still good practice to put
tweens = null; to remove ref to it and make it available for GC ?

Comment: Yes putting null to tweens is correct. But the method cleanup is not a ggod solution, infact there are two possibilities: 1) no other references to tweens exists, so nulling internal references is not necessary 2) other references to tweens exists, in this case you probably will break internal state of tweens coming to a not valid state. So generally it is not a good practice.